# using a class variable in LateUpdate()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I declare a class variable as follows (one of `MecAnim` bones that I wanna treat differently later on):

```
private Transform specialBone;
```

Then, I initialize it in `Start()` as follows:

```
specialBone = transform.Find("Pelvis/LeftShoulder/LeftUpperArm/LeftLowerArm/LeftHand");
```

Finally, I try to do something in `LateUpdate()` to see some effect (I am only just learning what I can do in `LateUpdate()` to modify the stuff happening in `Update()` etc...):

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    specialBone.position = specialBone.position + new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
}
```

However, I get the `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error message on the `LateUpdate()` line...

What am I missing or doing wrong that `specialBone` is still `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the variable specialBone to public and see in the editor if it found the transform which I think it cant(thus the null reference) because start runs first .CHECK the spelling in hierarchy and make sure you didn't miss an inner parent .

Comment: You are right -- it could not find it for the `public` class variable, but does that mean I should put the entire `transform.Find("Pelvis/LeftShoulder/LeftUpperArm/LeftLowerArm/LeftHand")` in the class variables section? Any work around to neatly define it in `Start`?

Comment: you cannot use the Find function in variables section(btw its not called variable section) . The neatest and fasted way is to define a public varaible ->> public transform specialBone ,and then drag the object from heirarchy to the script file in the editor .Nonetheless the way you are doing it is also correct but i think you missed a nesting level or some spelling mistake . Another way you can do it is ->>
 [SerializeField]
and define private variables under it and they will show up in the editor.